# Typo3 8.7: wrong redirect to landing page when using link action

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I'm currently having trouble calling an `action` from a `view` using this `link action`

`<f:link.action controller="Checklist" action="duplicate" arguments="{checklist: checklist}" class="clone">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</f:link.action>`

Instead of calling the action and running the code, the plugin simply redirects to the landing page of my website without throwing any errors.

I have never had this problem, other `actions` in the `checklist controller` can be called without any problem (!from the same view!).

Even when I change the Action code to this:

```
public function duplicateAction(\Vendor\someExt\Domain\Model\Checklist $checklist) {    
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($checklist);
  exit; 
}
```

it simply ignores all the code and redirects anyway.

I have added the action (like any other) inside the `ext_localconf` to `configurePlugin` to the callable Actions for the controller `checklist`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By redirect do you mean the generated link looks something like https://example.com/home or does the generated link redirect you but originally contains the action und controller parameters?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm getting redirected to the landing page but the `action and the controller aswell as the cHash parameters` are in the generated url displayed by the browser. All looks fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem myself. The problem was none-Typo3 related as it was Javascript code that intervened in the submitting process of the `link action` which lead to the redirect..